# Android 12+ animation splash screen API not working

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12

I am trying to add the new Android animation splash screen to my app, however, it is not showing.

theme.xml:

```
...
<style name="Theme.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/news_avd_v02</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.xxx.NoActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/pink_300</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">3000</item>

    <!-- Status bar and Nav bar configs -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
</style>
...
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplash">
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainDrawerActivity"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
```

MainDrawerActivity.kt:

```
...
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
  ...
  class MainDrawerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        ...
```

I have already tried to kill the app and relaunch it, it still not show the animation.

Answer (score 1):

replace windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon -> android: windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon